# biginteger array functions

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Are there any available functions for work with big integers?

I've found a module [intarray](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html), but functions from this module only work with `integer`, not `bigint`.

I miss a function for removing an item from an array. Something like the implementation of a "minus" operator in mentioned module:

> `int[] - int` (remove entries matching right argument from array)

Comment: arrays are immutable in pg, you have to do copy without requested numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Postgres 9.3 or newer

With the added [`array_remove(anyarray, anyelement)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html), the task is simple now:

```sql
test=> SELECT array_remove('{1,3,4,3}'::bigint[], 3);
 array_remove 
--------------
 {1,4}
```

#### Postgres 9.2 or older

Create a custom function. This one is reasonably fast:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arr_subtract(int8[], int8[])
  RETURNS int8[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT a
   FROM   unnest($1) WITH ORDINALITY x(a, ord)
   WHERE  a <> ALL ($2)
   ORDER  BY ord
   );
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT arr_subtract('{3,5,6,7,8,9}':: int8[], '{3,4,8}'::int8[]);
```

Result:

```
{5,6,7,9}
```

Allows to remove multiple values at once.
Keeps the original order of the array.
Does not work for NULL values.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)
- [Exclude matched array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819944/exclude-matched-array-elements/34821253#34821253)