# Exclude matched array elements

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

How can I exclude matched elements of one array from another?

Postgres code:

```
a1 := '{1, 2, 5, 15}'::int[];
a2 := '{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15}'::int[];

a3 := a2 ??magic_operator?? a1;
```

In `a3` I expect exactly '{3, 6, 7, 9}'

**Final Result**

My and lad2025 solutions works fine.

Solution with `array_position()` required **PostgreSQL 9.5** and later, executes x3 faster.

Comment: Are the elements in those arrays always sorted like they are in your example?

Comment: I can sort it like this, no prob

Comment: Result from [1,2,3] and [3,1,2] will be? Your question is unclear. Matched element means that it exist in both arrays or what?

Comment: Yes, left and right side confused. I mean, if both matched - exclude from output. right side, 5 not match - skip. left side not match - to output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional module [`intarray`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/intarray.html) provides a simple and fast [subtraction operator **`-`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/intarray.html#INTARRAY-OP-TABLE) for integer arrays, exactly the *magic_operator* you are looking for:

```
test=# SELECT '{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15}'::int[] - '{1, 2, 5, 15}'::int[] AS result;
 ?column?
-----------
 {3,6,7,9}
```

You need to install the module once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
```

It also provides special operator classes for indexes:

- [Postgresql intarray error: undefined symbol: pfree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491184/postgresql-intarray-error-undefined-symbol-pfree/10491433#10491433)

Note that it [only works for:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/intarray.html)

> ... null-free arrays of integers.

Comment: Great solution! Also I check, no bigint versions in latest 9.5

Comment: Also, function for int8[] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579701/biginteger-array-functions

Comment: @Dmitry: That [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8584080/939860) was a bit outdated. Consider the update.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `XOR` between arrays:

```
WITH set1 AS
(
 SELECT * FROM unnest('{1, 2, 5, 15}'::int[])
), set2 AS
(
 SELECT * FROM unnest('{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15}'::int[])
), xor AS
(
  (SELECT * FROM set1
   UNION 
   SELECT * FROM set2)
  EXCEPT
  (SELECT * FROM set1
   INTERSECT 
   SELECT * FROM set2)
)
SELECT array_agg(unnest ORDER BY unnest)
FROM xor
```

Output:

```
"{3,5,6,7,9}"
```

How it works:

1. Unnest both arrays
2. Calculate SUM
3. Calculate INTERSECT
4. From SUM - INTERSECT
5. Combine to array

Alternatively you could use sum of both minus(except) operations:

```
(A+B) - (A^B)
<=>
(A-B) + (B-A)
```

---

Utilizing `FULL JOIN`:

```
WITH set1 AS
(
 SELECT *
FROM unnest('{1, 2, 5, 15}'::int[])
), set2 AS
(
 SELECT *
 FROM unnest('{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15}'::int[])
)
SELECT array_agg(COALESCE(s1.unnest, s2.unnest) 
                 ORDER BY COALESCE(s1.unnest, s2.unnest))
FROM set1 s1
FULL JOIN set2 s2
  ON s1.unnest = s2.unnest
WHERE s1.unnest IS NULL
  OR s2.unnest IS NULL;
```

**EDIT:**

If you want only elements from second array that are not is first use simple `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT array_agg(unnest ORDER BY unnest)
FROM (SELECT * FROM unnest('{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15}'::int[])
      EXCEPT
      SELECT * FROM unnest('{1, 2, 5, 15}'::int[])) AS sub
```

Output:

```
"{3,6,7,9}"
```

Comment: Condition: Exactly output  '{3,6,7,9}'

Comment: Your definition of matched element is odd. For matched element I assumed that it exists in both tables.

Comment: The question seems to be about subtraction, not about `XOR`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter It was not so clear at the begining, that's why I produced "exlusive or" solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a little similar case and modify.

That SQL solve my case.

```
with elements (element) as (
   select unnest(ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15])
)
select array_agg(element)
from elements
where array_position(ARRAY[1, 2, 5, 15],element) is null
```

PostgreSQL 9.5 and later required.